# How to get rounded edges for caption boxes using caption/captionsetup

Tags: floats, captions

I use the following in my preamble to ensure a gray background for my captions underneath figures and tables:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}
\captionsetup{box=colorbox,boxcolor=light-gray,slc=off}
```

The resulting figures are as such:

[image]

My problem is that I want to have rounded edges, but have no idea to achieve this. The documentation for [caption](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/caption/caption-eng.pdf) does not specify all the parameters that can be passed to the `\captionsetup` function. In fact the `box=` and `boxcolor=`are nowhere to be found in that documentation. Is it possible to pass a parameter to round the edges of background caption box? And secondly, where can I find the full documentation for caption?

Comment: Since `colorbox` does not have round edges this won't work. And for the documentation of `caption`: Try [caption](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) on CTAN

Comment: Unfortunately these `caption` package commands and options are documented in the changelog only: http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/CHANGELOG  I'm currently updating the documentation (which still reflects the version 3.1 and not the current one 3.3) but progress is slow.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: I had to dig into the various `caption*.sty` files ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying `colorbox` trial does not provide rounded edges before since `\colorbox` just does not have them at all.

A trick is to replace `colorbox` with another caption-box -- it's a little bit tricky:

An undocumented feature of `caption` are the `\DeclareCaptionOption` and `\DeclareCaptionBox` macros -- use those to add an option named, say `stuffforbox` which is used by the underlying `mycaptionbox`, which is defined to be a `\newtcolorbox`.

For more configuration options see the `tcolorbox` manual, especially for spacing issues!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}
\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{mycaptionbox}[2][]{enhanced,colback=light-gray,#1}
\DeclareCaptionOption{stuffforbox}{\def\caption@stuffforbox{#1}}

\DeclareCaptionBox{mybox}{%
  \begin{mycaptionbox}[code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\caption@stuffforbox}}]
    #2%
  \end{mycaptionbox}%
}
\makeatother
\captionsetup{stuffforbox={drop shadow},box={mybox},boxcolor={light-gray},slc=off}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{An image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing thank you! I had this vague picture in my mind of how I wanted my figures to look like, but couldn't come up with the exact design. This is exactly it!