# How to put a color-filled frame around a caption in longtable?

Tags: captions, longtable, tcolorbox, framed

I would like to put a color-filled frame (for example with `tcolorbox` package) around the caption of a longtable, which I put into `\endlastfoot`. I used the answer to this question: [Boxed caption and figure, with colored caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224270/boxed-caption-and-figure-with-colored-caption) for my other figures/tables, but cannot make it work in the longtable-environment. I have used the answer to this question [Color a longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345589/color-a-longtable/345602#345602) to try to color the caption-multirow, but cannot make it look nice and framed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}

%Tabels:
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

%Adjusted Command to color the caption from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345589/color-a-longtable/345602#345602
\definecolor{lightGray}{gray}{0.95}
\def\ColorTabelHeader{lightGray}

\newcommand*{\BeginHeadcolor}{%
  \arrayrulecolor{gray}\toprule[0.7pt]
  \rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}%
  \noalign{%
    \kern-\belowrulesep
    \begingroup
      \color{\ColorTabelHeader}\hrule height\belowrulesep
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\EndHeadcolor}{%
  \noalign{%
    \begingroup
      \color{\ColorTabelHeader}%
      \hrule height\aboverulesep
    \endgroup
    \kern-\aboverulesep
  }%
  \toprule[0.7pt] \arrayrulecolor{black}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LTBeginHeadcolor}{%
  \arrayrulecolor{gray}\toprule[0.7pt]
    \vadjust pre{\kern-\belowrulesep}%
    \begingroup
      \color{\ColorTabelHeader}%
      \leaders\hrule height\belowrulesep\hfill
    \endgroup
  \cr
  \rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}%
}
\newcommand*{\LTEndHeadcolor}{%
  \multispan\LT@cols
    \begingroup
      \color{\ColorTabelHeader}%
      \leaders\hrule height\aboverulesep\hfill
    \endgroup
  \cr
  \noalign{%
    \kern-\aboverulesep
  }%
 \toprule[0.7pt] \arrayrulecolor{black}
}
\makeatother


% Settings for Longtable
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} 
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\columnwidth}
% To make it load faster
\setcounter{LTchunksize}{50}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
\begin{longtable}{c|c >{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c c >{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c c}
\LTBeginHeadcolor
\caption[]{\textbf{Caption:}
some information describing the content}\\
\LTEndHeadcolor \endfoot
\LTBeginHeadcolor
\caption[]{\textbf{Caption:}
this is a very long caption with some additional information regarding the parameters.\label{tab:Sample}}\\*
\rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\parbox{\LTcapwidth}{{\footnotesize This Information is so long, that I had to put it in an extra paragraph with a smaller font}}}\\
\LTEndHeadcolor
\endlastfoot 
    \toprule
   \multirow{2}[2]{*}[2mm]{\textbf{Parameter}} &      & \textbf{BLH} & \textbf{0h} & \textbf{4h} & \textbf{8h} \\
          &       & Median (SD) & Median (SD) & Median (SD) & Median (SD) \\
    \midrule  \endfirsthead
     \toprule    
   \multirow{2}[2]{*}[2mm]{\textbf{Parameter}} &      & \textbf{BLH} & \textbf{0h} & \textbf{4h} & \textbf{8h} \\
          &       & Median (SD) & Median (SD) & Median (SD) & Median (SD) \\
    \midrule     \endhead
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[0,3cm]    
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}%%


\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try to build a solution using \DeclareCaptionBox. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280960/how-to-get-rounded-edges-for-caption-boxes-using-caption-captionsetup/280963#280963 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128103/hang-caption-in-lstlisting/128141#128141

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks to your information I found a solution. I am going to post it as a possible solution, so others might be able to used it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Axel I found a possible solution for my problem. Since I am relatively new to Latex and not really used to Macros, please tell me about any mistakes I made or just edit my answer:

The code for the color-filled framed LTcaptionbox:

```
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

    \makeatletter
    \newtcolorbox{LTcaptionbox}[7][]{enhanced, colframe=gray, colback=gray!30, arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, boxrule=0.7pt, before={}, #1}
    \DeclareCaptionOption{stuffforbox}{\def\caption@stuffforbox{#1}}

    \DeclareCaptionBox{myLTbox}{%
      \begin{LTcaptionbox}[code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\caption@stuffforbox}}]
        #2%
      \end{LTcaptionbox}%
    }
    \makeatother
    \captionsetup[longtable]{stuffforbox={}, box={myLTbox}, slc=off}
```

And my edited table (I added the 'tabu' package to fill the whole page and adjust '\bottomrule' and the LTCaptionbox to the same width)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}

%Tabels:
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabu}


\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{LTcaptionbox}[7][]{enhanced, colframe=gray, colback=gray!30, arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, boxrule=0.7pt, before={}, #1}
\DeclareCaptionOption{stuffforbox}{\def\caption@stuffforbox{#1}}

\DeclareCaptionBox{myLTbox}{%
  \begin{LTcaptionbox}[code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\caption@stuffforbox}}]
    #2%
  \end{LTcaptionbox}%
}
\makeatother
\captionsetup[longtable]{stuffforbox={}, box={myLTbox}, slc=off}

% Settings for Longtable
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} 
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\glueexpr(\textwidth-10mm-1,4pt)\relax} % minus Distance text- to outer edge of the bounding-box on both sides
% To make it load faster
\setcounter{LTchunksize}{50}

\begin{document}



\begin{longtabu}{X|X X X X X}
\caption[]{\textbf{Caption:} some information describing the content}\endfoot
\caption[CaptionLOT]{\textbf{Caption:} this is a very long caption with some additional information regarding the parameters.\label{tab:Sample}\\*
{\footnotesize This Information is so long, that I had to put it in an extra paragraph with a smaller font}}
\endlastfoot 
    \toprule
   \multirow{2}[2]{*}[2mm]{\textbf{Parameter}} &      & \textbf{BLH} & \textbf{0h} & \textbf{4h} & \textbf{8h} \\
          &       & Median (SD) & Median (SD) & Median (SD) & Median (SD) \\
    \midrule  \endfirsthead
     \toprule    
   \multirow{2}[2]{*}[2mm]{\textbf{Parameter}} &      & \textbf{BLH} & \textbf{0h} & \textbf{4h} & \textbf{8h} \\
          &       & Median (SD) & Median (SD) & Median (SD) & Median (SD) \\
    \midrule     \endhead
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\
    Parameter & Group1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\*
    {[unit]} & Group2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \vspace{0,3cm}\\    
    \bottomrule \addlinespace[1pt]
\end{longtabu}%%


\end{document}
```

PS: I could not use '\columncolor' with the X columns of 'Longtabu'. Does anyone know a possible solution for this problem?
If you want to keep the 'Longtable'-Environment, you can just use:

```
\newlength\q
\setlength\q{\dimexpr 0.166\textwidth -2\tabcolsep\relax}
```

and

```
\begin{longtable}{p{\q}|p{\q} >{\columncolor[gray]{.95}\centering\arraybackslash}p{\q} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\q} >{\columncolor[gray]{.95}\centering\arraybackslash}p{\q} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\q}}
```